# How to be informed when a HDD is detected in Linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, hard-drive, scsi

We have an embedded Linux build that starts with a HDD in sleep mode (hardware). The software then starts and enables power to the drive. Linux detects the drive fine:

```
ata1: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4050000 action 0x42 frozen
ata1: soft resetting port
ata1: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl F0000)
ata1.00: ATA-8, max UDMA/133, 976773168 sectors: LBA48 NCQ (depth 0/32)
ata1.00: ata1: dev 0 multi count 0
ata1.00: configured for UDMA/133
ata1: EH complete
  Vendor: ATA       Model: Hitachi HCS5C105  Rev: JC2O
  Type:   Direct-Access                      ANSI SCSI revision: 05
SCSI device sda: 976773168 512-byte hdwr sectors (500108 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
SCSI device sda: 976773168 512-byte hdwr sectors (500108 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
 sda: sda1 sda2
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi disk sda
sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
```

Unfortunately the software attempts to access the drive before the above SCSI detect happens. We could add a sleep but this is not a reliable mechanism as we have noticed that the time taken to detect is non-deterministic.

Is there any way to get the kernel/hotplug/etc. system to report when the HDD is detected?

Thanks.

Comment: is it not possible to start the hd at start up then use hdparm to tell it to spindown in the startup scripts?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The hardware is wired as such and it requires a level change on an output pin. The pin might be available during kernel init, so I would need to check that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is somewhere in the [udev](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev.html) device manager ([wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev)). It is fully usable in an embedded environement.

It allows you to [write rules](http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html) that are able to launch scripts/programs when some devices are detected.

Something like this could do the stuff :

```
KERNEL=="sda", RUN+="/usr/bin/my_program"
```

If you have an old kernel, you may have the [hotplug](http://linux.die.net/man/8/hotplug) system activated.

The last chance wouls be the [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) tool that let you monitor anything in your file system (even /dev directory :)).

Comment: Unfortunately our system is not running udev otherwise that would be nice. It does seem to support kernel hot plugging though I have not seen `mdev -s` start anywhere

Comment: @user626201 : old kernel ? maybe you're kernel is using hotplug daemon ?

Comment: @user626201 : weel, I edited my answer to add references to hotplug system and inotify.

Comment: I tried inotify on the sysfs directory `/sys/block` without success. I will try the `/dev`. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a set of options to do this, from the simplest to the most complicated:

- **Manual polling**. Simply write a shell script that polls until the hard disk becomes available before actually using it. Granted, this is not the nicest solution, but it works and is simple.
- **mdev**. If your embedded Linux system is Busybox based (which I hope it is!), then Busybox integrates the `mdev` program. Its usage is very simple and is documented at http://git.buildroot.net/busybox/tree/docs/mdev.txt. `mdev` will very easily allow you to run a shell script when a device gets detected. If you already have Busybox in your embedded Linux system, this is definitely the solution I would recommend.
- **udev**, as proposed by others. This is the solution used in full blown desktop/server systems. It has more dependencies than `mdev` and is a bit harder to setup. If you only have your hard disk detection problem to solve, I'd say that using `udev` is a bit overkill, but if you intend to use it for other purposes, why not.
- **udev** + **udisks** + **dbus**, this is actually what is used on full blown systems. `udisks` is a daemon that uses `udev` to be notified of new storage devices appearing in the system, it gets some additional informations about them and then send a message over D-Bus. It allows provides D-Bus services to manipulate the storage devices.

I hope this gives you an overview of the possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks - we have resorted to the manual polling. mdev and udev are not supported :( Unfortunately the customer required this particular chip and we are limited with the tools supports as the chip is reasonably old.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the uevent netlink socket - you will get the same events as udevd

see http://lwn.net/Articles/242046/